# .resx file (culture-specific) with singleton pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

Honestly this is first time into resx files for me. I try to investigate what bad and good practice and finds that there exist as much ideas as lines for someone soon to translate.

As whole I got into this idea,

1. Create all "Resources/Purpose.lang-COUNTRY.resx" as needed
2. Create a singleton that loads currentculture and hook corresponding resx file.
3. Whenever needed, use SingletonName.GetString("StringVariable");

   - How about using Singleton here?
   - Yes/no what's better practice?

I'm also a little confused of how to find correct name to refer the embedded resx.

```
ResourceManager rm = 
  new ResourceManager("SomeLang.en-US", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

It searches for a .resource (the files are named resx) and I can't find the resource specification in dll through reflector..

Comment: Whats the question then?

Comment: Are you using .NET MVC or Web forms? I have a nice simple example of one approach in MVC3?

Comment: This should be pure c# usage (business/data logic). There are other solutions needed when embedding resources into ASP / MVC3 controls, i know so - but will come into that later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fairly straight forward approach for internationalization in ASP.NET MVC3 that I thought may give you a different angle to consider / compare your current approach with.

http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx

Comment: Thank's. Your probably right about it. But I will tell, as a comment, that your proposed answer is not even close to what I ask for, however it might be a good (complex though) solution to a MVC layer later on.

Comment: I knew it didn't anwser directly but thought it may help. I am working on something similar at the moment so I will update with any extra information :)